# How do I restore multiple monitor support for integrated ATI Radeon 3000 graphics after a Windows update?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, windows-update, amd-radeon, integrated-graphics

I wasn't able to find a solution for this problem. The ones offered previously are for other versions of this integrated graphics chipset and do not offer an explicit set of instructions for how to easily remedy the situation.

Comment: A question should contain a question, if you already know the answer to your question, then submit an answer to your question

Comment: Your “answer” indicates you should select the most recent version of the driver but in your screenshot you have a driver from 2015 selected

Answer (score 0):

This fix applies specifically to setups where the multiple monitor feature was working properly prior to the fall creators update but does not work after the update. Though it could be used as a resource to aid in a new installation/upgrade to Windows 10 as well.

1. Open the Control Panel. Start>Windows System>Control Panel

[image]

2. Open the Device Manger. View By>Small icons>Device Manager

[image]
[image]
[image]

3. Expand Display adapters. Double click "Display adapters"

[image]

4. Open ATI Radeon 3000 Graphics Properties. Double click "ATI Radeon 3000 Graphics"

[image]

5. Click the Driver tab.
6. Click the Update Driver button.

[image]

7. Click "Browse my computer for driver software".

[image]

8. Click "Let me pick from a list of available drivers on my computer".

[image]

9. Select the 8.970.100.9001 version of the "ATI Radeon 3000 Graphics" driver.
10. Click the Next button.

[image]

11. Wait for the "Windows has successfully updated your device drivers" message. The screen will flicker and there will be some status sounds.

[image]

Your multiple monitors should now identify properly in the Settings>System>Display dialog.

[image]